# Windows 8.1 cordova: Using jquery's find method on XML

Tags: jquery, xml, windows, cordova

I am working on a cordova 4.3.1 application that has to modify xml code read from xlsx and pptx documents, after unzipping them. In order to do that, we use jquery's `$.parseXML` method and then perform some changes in the xml. To reach the tags where we need to change the xml, we use jquery's `find` method. All works fine on iOS. However, when we test it on windows 8.1, sometimes the `find` returns an empty jquery result when called on some of a pptx's xml (xlsx works fine, but we use the `find` quite less often than on pptx).

I have taken a look at the object on which the `find` doesn't work, and it looks pretty much the same as it does on iOS (most of the object's content is the same, some elements appears only on iOS (such as `baseURI`, `currentScript`) and multiple appears only on Windows (such as `alinkcolor`, `all`, `ATTRIBUTE_NODE`)). One suspicious thing i noticed is that the xml object's location attribute contains "Unexpected call to method or property access" on windows, whereas it is null on iOS.

Also, since the xml was generated by Excel and Powerpoint, i am confident that it is valid.

Does anyone have an idea why this behavior happens on windows? My search mostly found problems where people used the `find` method without the `$.parseXML`, which is not the case here.

### Small code extracts

**On xlsx, and works for both :**

initialization: `this.xmlData = $.parseXML(this.zip.file(sheetZipPath).asText());`

working find : `var cells = $(this.xmlData).find("c");`

**On pptx, and works for only iOS:**

initialization (working for both) : `this.currentSlideXML = $.parseXML(this.zipContent.file(slideZipPath).asText();`

not working find : `var paragraphs = $(this.currentSlideXML).find("p");`
Considering the line above, when i put a breakpoint on it and try different selectors that are located under a certain amount of `childNodes` (even "sld", which is right under document in this case), i always get an empty search result (ie. a jquery object with a length of 0).

I can't really copy the xml in here considering its size, but if you create a pptx or xlsx file, save it, rename it as .zip and then unzip it, you can find one that would have a similar structure.

### In short

I'm getting weird behavior from the `find` method on windows when used on XML parsed with jquery's `parseXML`, and i'd like to know if i'm missing an obvious mistake in my code, or if there is some explanation on why this happens on windows and not on iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was the the XML namespace. For the pptx file, the xml was parsed while taking into account the tag's namespace in the nodeName. So, when jquery tried to match my selector, it didn't find the tags it should because the selector wasn't entirely the same as the nodeName (ex: i was using `find("p")`, but the node was called "a:p", so i needed to instead use `find("a\\:p")`.

So in the end, it was working on iOS and not on windows because both platform use different xml parsers.